# What do we mean by Node Impurity ?Ref-Random Forest

Tags: r, random-forest

I got mentioned it here. I researched on Google but could not find an explanation.

```
    importance(x, type=NULL, class=NULL, scale=TRUE, ...)
    Arguments
    x an object of class randomForest.
    type either 1 or 2, specifying the type of importance measure (1=mean decrease in
    accuracy, 2=mean decrease in **node impurity**

).
```

Comment: Node impurity represents how well the trees split the data.  There are several impurity measures; one option is the Gini index.  When determining the importance in the variable, you can use the mean decrease in accuracy (i.e. misclassification) or mean decrease in node impurity (i.e. Gini index).  Most people use accuracy to assess variable importance.

Comment: Please, don't confuse Gini index and Gini impurity

Answer (score 5):

In simple terms, let's say you are trying to predict whether you will go out or not based on weather parameters.

If it is raining you will definitely not go. So all observations at this point are 'No' i.e. pure node

While if is is not raining you will check weather temperature is below 20 C then "yes" else "no". This node is impure node.

You can measure this impurity based on metric of your choice. Thus deciding how you split the variables (concept from decision trees https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zze7SKuz9QQ)

You can choose your impurity measure based on requirement as Peter has suggested.

Hope this helps.